# Tomcat Server Return 403 Status

Tags: http, tomcat, put

I have  a strange issue, My Spring Rest API works perfectly for HTTP GET,POST,DELETE and PUT.
This web service is hosted locally on a Tomcat 7

However the same Web Service throws a 403 for DELETE and PUT when hosted on Tomcat 7 that is located on a remote Serverbut works fine for GET and POST.

I have made the below confguration change according the below link(since i read PUT and Delete are disabled by default)

http://www.codereye.com/2010/12/configure-tomcat-to-accept-http-put.html

But i am finding it hard to understand how DELETE and PUT are working fine locally.

What is the issue?

Comment: I met same issue one different point is I use jersey restful. Eager to know the solution